# ¿Cómo crear una columna nueva con valores de otro dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo dos `dataframe`:

```
df1 =pd.Dataframe({"descripcion":["a","b","c"],"cantidad":[1,2,3]})

df2 = pd.Dataframe({"descripcion": ["a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"], "mes":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], "ventas":[5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3]}).
```

Quiero crear un nuevo `dataframe` que contenga la columna descripción del `df1`, cantidad del `df1` y 3 columnas más, una por cada mes y que en cada columna mes esté el valor de la venta que coincida con esa descripción y ese mes. Por ejemplo, la primera fila sería:

```
(a,1,mes1, 5)
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

para hacer lo que pides debes crear un nuevo DataFrame, yo lo he llamado `df3` y ahi crear vacias las columnas que quieras que contenga para despueus sustituirlas.
Este es el codigo que te propongo:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 =pd.DataFrame({"descripcion":["a","b","c"],"cantidad":[1,2,3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"descripcion": ["a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"], "mes":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], "ventas":[5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3]})

df3= pd.DataFrame({"descripcion":[], "cantidad":[], "mes":[], "descripcion2":[], "ventas":[]})

df3["descripcion"]= df1["descripcion"]
df3["cantidad"]= df1["cantidad"]
df3["mes"]= df2["mes"]
df3["descripcion2"]= df2["descripcion"]
df3["ventas"]= df2["ventas"]

print(df3)
```

No se si quieres que la descripcion del df2 aparezca porque en el texto pones que si y en cuando muestras como quieres que quede el DataFrame no lo pones. SI no quieres que aparezca, bastaria con eliminar la columna `"descripcion2":[]` y la linea en la que se le asigna valor

PD: OJO! se escribe `DataFrame` no `Dataframe`. Para la proxima vez acuerdate de poner las librerias que estas usando.

Un saludo, espero que te ayude.

Comment: Buen día, al igual que la otra respuesta, te recomendaría “ocultar” esta respuesta hasta que la pregunta sea editada y se apegue a las normas del sitio. Saludos